# Android studio importing in gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am new to **Android Studio** and was just trying to *import my eclipse project*. i am trying to resolve this issue for quite a while now but unable to. 
I have a mainactivity project which uses mmany other libraries *staggeredgridview, devsmart, google maps and appcompactv7*. I am getting following 2 errors.

Note: mainactivity project is the one which i am working on and uses other external libraries.

```
Error:(7, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library B:\Android Studio Projects\mainActivity\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.5.87\AndroidManifest.xml 

Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" to force usage
:mainActivity:processDebugManifest FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':mainActivity:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

**build.gradle of mainactivity**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.staggeredgridviewdemo"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 16
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':devsmartAndroid')
    compile project(':staggeredGridViewmaster')
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
}
```

**build.grade for devsmart**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 4
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar')
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0') {
        // really use 19.1.0 even if something else resolves higher
       force = true
    }
}
```

**build.gradle for sttageredgridview**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 16
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0') {
        // really use 19.1.0 even if something else resolves higher
       force = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just edit `minsdk` of your **build.gradle of mainactivity** to `9` :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.staggeredgridviewdemo"
    minSdkVersion 9 // changed line
    targetSdkVersion 16
}
```

*Note : Also did the same  for other libs if there minsdk is small then 9*

Comment: I think , by incrementing the minSdkVersion to 9 the app can only work in API level >=9 , So How can i solve this problem without incrementing the minSdkVersion ??

Answer (score 1):

Please open your manifest file and write the bellow code it will work

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms"/>
```

and add the list of libraries for uses-skd separated by comma

Answer (score 0):

Go to all the manifest files or build.gradle files of all the projects and make the minSDKversions the same.8 for instance.